# How do you cast an array of unknown type to type []any?

Tags: go, interface

Assuming only arrays are passed as arguments to the `arr` parameter, I would like each call of `unpackArray()` to return the argument casted from its original array type to type `[]any`.

```
package main

func unpackArray(arr any) []any {
    return arr.([]any)
}

func main() {
    myArr1 := []string {"Hey"}
    myArr2 := []int {60}
    unpackArray(myArr1)
    unpackArray(myArr2)
}
```

However, this code yields error `panic: interface conversion: interface {} is []string, not []interface {}`.  So it is not allowing me to cast an interface whose static type is not type `[]any` to type `[]any`.

So, given I know that `arr`'s static type is some type of array, and without changing the `arr` parameter's initialization type from `any`, how could I convert `arr` to type `[]any` using this function?

*(I am encountering the same problem with maps where I cannot cast from an arbitrary map type to type `map[any]any`, but I am guessing the solution to this issue would be similar to the solution for arrays.)*

Comment: https://go.dev/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go does not have a builtin "cast" like this, but you can write a function to do it.

You may use [reflection](https://godoc.org/reflect) to convert a slice of any type to []any:

```
func unpackArray(s any) []any {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(s)
    r := make([]any, v.Len())
    for i := 0; i < v.Len(); i++ {
        r[i] = v.Index(i).Interface()
    }
    return r
}
```

You can also use generics in Go 1.18 or later:

```
func unpackArray[S ~[]E, E any](s S) []any {
    r := make([]any, len(s))
    for i, e := range s {
        r[i] = e
    }
    return r
}
```

Both versions of these functions work as requested in the question:

```
myArr1 := []string {"Hey"}
myArr2 := []int {60}
unpackArray(myArr1)
unpackArray(myArr2)
```

Notes:

- Go does not have "cast" like some other languages.  Go has the somewhat related [type assertion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions) and [conversion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions) features.
- The expression `arr.([]any)` is a type assertion. The expression asserts that the concrete value in the interface `arr` has type `[]any`.  The expression does not do any conversion.
- The code in the question uses [slices](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Slice_types) , not [arrays](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Array_types) as written in the title.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do that directly, because it's not the same thing.

---

`any` is the same of `interface{}` and each `interface{}` is two-pointers (the first one is the "metadata"/"type-information" and the second one the pointer to the original data).

If you have `[]uint{60, 42}` you have one slice that each element is 8-byte (considering 64bits). So, if you force it to be `[]any`, each element now take 16 bytes, that breaks everything. *You can do it using `unsafe`.*

The only way to "cast" is copying the information, so, you can create a new slice of `[]any` and then append each value into that new slice.

---

One example of copying is:

```
// You can edit this code!

package main

func unpackArray[T any](arr any) (r []any) {
    o := arr.([]T)
    r = make([]any, len(o))

    for i, v := range o {
        r[i] = any(v)
    }

    return r
}

func main() {
    myArr1 := []string{"Hey"}
    myArr2 := []int{60}
    unpackArray[string](myArr1)
    unpackArray[int](myArr2)
}
```

*However, that doesn't make so much sense, since you can use generics in another way.*

Comment: Your code worked exactly as described and was very useful, but, since @stephanie gave an answer that requires less on the user-end, I am marking hers as correct.  Regardless, thank you for the help!